# Passing global variables in Tornado classes

Tags: python, global-variables, tornado

To date I have been passing variables from one `Tornado` class to another by declaring them as `global`. I think that this might not be the ideal way to do so. Here's a sample of my code:

```
class MHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@tornado.web.asynchronous

def get(self):
    self.render('index.html')

def post(self):
    global account_age

    age = self.get_argument('age')

    account_age = [age]


class AgeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):    
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@gen.engine

def open(self):
    global account_age


    print 'Your account is overdue by: ', account_age
```

I would like to know, whether in this framework what would be the more appropriate way to share variables.

I've only been doing python and Tornado for just a few weeks, so please excuse my ignorance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I wouldn't do that. Even in this simplified example it is clear that you have a race condition between the POST and the websocket opening. How can you guarantee that the person making the POST was the same person opening the websocket?

I usually hold onto a reference to each websocket connection in a global list/dict. Some kind of reference that lets me write the server side output to the correct connection.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I changed my code now, so the only communication between the client-server is through websockets. It has also meant that I could eliminate all the global variables in the code.

Comment: Sounds good, to elaborate a bit more. If you look at the tornado chat demo code they use a global list of "waiters" that live on one of the classes. Maybe overkill depending on your application though https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py